# listing command in prolog gives strange 'long' return in SWI-Prolog

Tags: prolog, swi-prolog

when I open SWI-Prolog and I type the command "listing." it should return just yes and after consulting a knowledge base, it should just return the predicates instead it returns:

```
?- listing.

:- dynamic exception/3.
:- multifile exception/3.


:- multifile prolog_clause_name/2.


:- multifile prolog_predicate_name/2.


:- dynamic library_directory/1.
:- multifile library_directory/1.

library_directory(B) :-
    '$parms':
    (   cached_library_directory(local, A=lib, A),
        B=A
    ).
library_directory(B) :-
    '$parms':
    (   cached_library_directory(user,
                                 expand_file_name('~/lib/prolog', [A]),
                                 A),
        B=A
    ).
library_directory(B) :-
    '$parms':
    (   cached_library_directory(system,
                                 absolute_file_name(swi(library), A),
                                 A),
        B=A
    ).
library_directory(B) :-
    '$parms':
    (   cached_library_directory(clp,
                                 absolute_file_name(swi('library/clp'), A),
                                 A),
        B=A
    ).

:- thread_local thread_message_hook/3.
:- dynamic thread_message_hook/3.
:- volatile thread_message_hook/3.


:- dynamic expand_answer/2.
:- multifile expand_answer/2.


:- dynamic file_search_path/2.
:- multifile file_search_path/2.

file_search_path(library, A) :-
        library_directory(A).
file_search_path(swi, A) :-
        system:current_prolog_flag(home, A).
file_search_path(foreign, swi(B)) :-
    system:
    (   current_prolog_flag(arch, A),
        atom_concat('lib/', A, B)
    ).
file_search_path(foreign, swi(A)) :-
    system:
    (   (   current_prolog_flag(windows, true)
        ->  A=bin
        ;   A=lib
        )
    ).
file_search_path(path, C) :-
    system:
    (   getenv('PATH', A),
        (   current_prolog_flag(windows, true)
        ->  atomic_list_concat(B, ;, A)
        ;   atomic_list_concat(B, :, A)
        ),
        '$member'(C, B),
        '$no-null-bytes'(C)
    ).
file_search_path(user_profile, app_preferences('.')).
file_search_path(app_preferences, app_data('.')).
file_search_path(app_data, B) :-
    '$toplevel':
    (   current_prolog_flag(windows, true),
        catch(win_folder(appdata, A), _, fail),
        atom_concat(A, '/SWI-Prolog', B),
        (   exists_directory(B)
        ->  true
        ;   catch(make_directory(B), _, fail)
        )
    ).
file_search_path(app_preferences, A) :-
        '$toplevel':catch(expand_file_name(~, [A]), _, fail).
file_search_path(autoload, library('.')).
file_search_path(pack, app_data(pack)).
file_search_path(pack, swi(pack)).
file_search_path(library, A) :-
        '$pack':pack_dir(_, prolog, A).
file_search_path(foreign, A) :-
        '$pack':pack_dir(_, foreign, A).
file_search_path(pce, A) :-
        link_xpce:pcehome_(A).
file_search_path(library, pce('prolog/lib')).
file_search_path(foreign, pce(B)) :-
    link_xpce:
    (   current_prolog_flag(arch, A),
        atom_concat('lib/', A, B)
    ).

:- dynamic message_hook/3.
:- multifile message_hook/3.


:- dynamic prolog_event_hook/1.
:- multifile prolog_event_hook/1.


:- multifile prolog_list_goal/1.


:- dynamic prolog_exception_hook/4.
:- multifile prolog_exception_hook/4.
prolog_exception_hook(error(A, context(D, B)), error(A, context(prolog_stack(J), B)), G, C) :-
    prolog_stack:
    (   current_prolog_flag(backtrace, true),
        (   atom(C)
        ->  debug(backtrace,
                  'Got uncaught (guard = ~q) exception ~p (Ctx0=~p)',
                  [C, A, D]),
            stack_guard(C)
        ;   prolog_frame_attribute(C, predicate_indicator, E),
            debug(backtrace,
                  'Got exception ~p (Ctx0=~p, Catcher=~p)',
                  [A, D, E]),
            stack_guard(E)
        ),
        (   current_prolog_flag(backtrace_depth, F)
        ->  F>0
        ;   F=20
        ),
        get_prolog_backtrace(G, F, H),
        debug(backtrace, 'Stack = ~p', [H]),
        clean_stack(H, I),
        join_stacks(D, I, J)
    ).

:- multifile message_property/2.


:- dynamic prolog_load_file/2.
:- multifile prolog_load_file/2.


:- dynamic portray/1.
:- multifile portray/1.

:- dynamic prolog_file_type/2.
:- multifile prolog_file_type/2.

prolog_file_type(pl, prolog).
prolog_file_type(prolog, prolog).
prolog_file_type(qlf, prolog).
prolog_file_type(qlf, qlf).
prolog_file_type(A, executable) :-
        system:current_prolog_flag(shared_object_extension, A).

:- dynamic resource/3.
:- multifile resource/3.


:- dynamic expand_query/4.
:- multifile expand_query/4.

true.
```

Why is it returning this instead of the true/yes?? I can't seem to find the answer online. When I give the listing command after consulting a knowledge base it gives a similar response, except with the predicates in the middle of the long story. Also listing/1 and listing/0 etc... just give errors (also after consulting a knowledge base.

gr

Comment: *It should return just yes*... that's what you're assuming, but the documentation doesn't say this. (Actually the documentation says very little!) In SWI Prolog, listing shows you some of the predefined predicates SWI Prolog has that are considered part of the "user module". This is often inconvenient, but there's no reason to assume that it won't. You can list a single predicate or fact via, `listing(predicate_name)`. By the way, `listing/1` just means `listing` with 1 argument, and `listing/0` means `listing` with no arguments. You don't type those in literally as queries.

Comment: I assumed it because the command was used in the book we use for the course.  Thanks for the help. I'll look for other commands to use.

Comment: The behavior in SWI is different than in GNU Prolog, for example. So it varies.